# Setting the height of a span element to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a theme / style for a piece of software.

Currently, the code looks like such:

http://jsfiddle.net/afseW/1/

The relevant code is:

```
body div[type*=privmsg] .sender {
    font-weight: 700;
    width:134px;
    text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px; 
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height:22px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    padding-right:5px;
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Note that in fiddle, for some reason, the text is collapsing onto the second line, whereas in the client, the image looks like this:

[image: What the client currently shows]

Granted, a span is not meant to be a block, hence I've given it the property of: `display: inline-block;`

But how do I get the height to inherit the parent p block?

Comment: Last line (the question) is height not width!

Comment: I think you should change your DOM structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the spans are a set width, probably the easiest thing to do here is just make the span have a absolute position.

```
body div[type*=privmsg] .sender,
body div[type*=action] .sender {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    ...
}
```

Then add padding to the parent element:

```
body span.message {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 140px;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afseW/3/

**PS**: please provide a trimmed down version in jsfiddle next time, the html and css here is pretty epic.

Answer (score 1):

I changed DOM structure. See the inline style. In the first `div` (.message) I prefer a better solution adding a `.clearfix` class, see [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

```
<div class="message" type="privmsg" style="overflow: auto;">
  <div class="sender-cont" style="width: 30%; float: left;">
    <span class="sender" ondblclick="Textual.nicknameDoubleClicked()"   oncontextmenu="Textual.openStandardNicknameContextualMenu()" type="myself" nick="shamil" colornumber="20">+shamil</span>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 70%; float: left;">
Welcome to <span class="channel" ondblclick="Textual.channelNameDoubleClicked()" oncontextmenu="Textual.openChannelNameContextualMenu()">#textual-testing</span>! This channel is for the users of the Textual IRC Client to test scripts and do other activities in an unregulated environment. — <span class="inline_nickname" ondblclick="Textual.inlineNicknameDoubleClicked()" oncontextmenu="Textual.openInlineNicknameContextualMenu()" colornumber="3">milky</span>'s law states: "On IRC, after a user has executed a command that outputs interesting information to a channel (i.e. /sysinfo), then there will be at least two users that do the same."
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Believe me, I'd love to change the DOM structure, it'd make things so much easier, but I can only deal with what I've given, and I can't change the DOM structure, sadly.